# Copy the datavalidation of Existing row and apply it to newly inserted row using c# EPP Plus

Tags: c#, epplus

I am trying get the drop down list And conditional formatting of existing rows and applying it to newly added row using c# EPP Plus.
is there any way to it in using sheet.InsertRow(2,1) or  sheet.Cells[1,2].Copy(sheet.Cells[1,2]) any of the method .
I dont want to add new list in drop down which is already there like
var textValidation = sheet.DataValidations.AddListValidation("B:B");
textValidation.Formula.Values.Add("male");
I want to copy listvalidation which is already there.

Thanks !!!